# Adding one extra class to a column and filling the value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

I have a table in the below format:

[image]

Reproduce code:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE reasons
(
Reasons INT ,
Counts_students VARCHAR(50) ,
total_count int
);

INSERT INTO reasons
VALUES ( 'A',2,null),
( 'B',3,null),
('C',8,null),
('D',1,null),
('E',2,null),
('F',5,null),
(NULL,NULL,45)
```

The final output introduces a new row in the "Reasons" category as "rest", which is essentially the total across the total_count- count_students

[image]

Any help is truly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the the tow result columns for all rows that have reasons that are no NULL and then `UNION ALL` a simple SELECT with tow aggregation functions

> ```
> SELECT reasons,Counts_students FROM reasons WHERE reasons IS NOT NULL
> UNION SELECT 'Rest', (SELECT MAX(total_count) - SUM(Counts_students) FROM reasons)
> ```
>
> ```
> reasons | Counts_students
> :------ | :--------------
> A       | 2              
> B       | 3              
> C       | 8              
> D       | 1              
> E       | 2              
> F       | 5              
> Rest    | 24
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e8f7dd9d5079577376bb03d7b7f9b863)*

As Ergest Basha pointed ou the subselect isn't really necessary

> ```
> SELECT reasons,Counts_students 
> FROM reasons 
> WHERE reasons IS NOT NULL
> UNION 
> SELECT 'Rest', MAX(total_count) - SUM(Counts_students) 
> FROM reasons
> ```
>
> ```
> reasons | Counts_students
> :------ | :--------------
> A       | 2              
> B       | 3              
> C       | 8              
> D       | 1              
> E       | 2              
> F       | 5              
> Rest    | 24
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90684e1cf4dbab499f5e5c737c0a84a4)*

Comment: That's the definitive answer. Great.

Comment: You could simplify it a little bit https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=90684e1cf4dbab499f5e5c737c0a84a4 no need to use SELECT  twice after the union